# Django logic and where to put it?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django, but I recently created my first application. I am wondering if I put my logic in the wrong places. From the Django book, I got that logic should but put into the views and data in models. But I have recently read that views should be as small as possible and let models handle the logic. My problem is my views handle **all** my logic while my models only handle data going to and from my database. Have I messed up when creating this app, and if so, how would I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Django's philosophy / best practices encourage "**fat models thin controllers**" (controllers being Views in Django). Having tried both ways, it definitely works better with the "fat models" approach. Keeping the logic as close to the data models makes it more reusable and you can there are many features in Django that work better that way.

One example would be returning a paginated list view. If you need to calculate something for every object in a queryset, you could

- loop over it in the view doing the calculation
- or you could add a model method then call it on every iteration in the template.

Looping over the queryset in the view will do the calculation on the whole queryset - not good if you are only showing 10 objects from a list of 1000.

Calling a model method from the template, the calculation will only be done on the 10 objects on that page.

Obviously you can add some more code to the view to only do that calculation on the objects on that page, but then thats extra code that isn't needed if you go the other route. If you need the same calculation on another page, keeping the logic in a model method will be reusable without any alteration, while you will need to cut and paste it in the view, or create a new method. While its not a huge difference, lots of small things like this start to add up.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have "Fat Models, Skinny Views." Many of Django experts will give you this tip. Google this phrase and you will find some resources that are saying "Fat Models, Skinny Views," or "Fat Models, Skinny Controllers." By the way, Django creators named Controllers as Views, and Views as Templates which maybe will cause some misunderstanding while reading articles about MVC which is MTV in Django.

Answer (score 0):

No you haven't mess it up. You can find your solution through experience (years of developing).

So, either using fat models and thin views or the opposite its up to you and your application requirements.

As you learn you'll discover new techniques and methods that will help you extend your "logic" and your app implementation.

At the beggining you'll make mistakes, but that's alright. We need them to become better developers, coders etc.

So my advice is: *keep calm and learn (good practices)*!

Comment: Am I right in thinking that "fat models and thin views" is generally in terms of large applications and needing an ORM? I'm constantly secretly thinking the same as the OP as I try to build :P

Comment: No. The one does not imply the other. You can have whatever you want as long as you keep youserlf [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and consistent. Me, for example, in some projects I have fat models, fat views and thin templates. In others I have thin models, fat views and fat templates. It always depends on each project and the way you handle each. The hard part is (as always) the beggining...

Comment: Interesting. And yes to the last part; for me, breaking into `django` also meant learning JS and HTML. When you know you can cover the python part in a way you recognise in `views`, it's easy just to ditch `models` entirely. For small applications, I can ensure my own (minor) SQL is safe etc. Then again, the web is so daunting that you constantly feel that you're missing some protection you don't see by doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is simple. And I would say that it is not actually messed up if your logic lies in views mostly.

The most repetitive functions and logic which you have used in views in multiple functions, you can create a function defined in model and then call that function in views. (you can do it step by step)

For example if it is a social network and you are setting the city of the user. Now as your app grows, possibly there will be many functions and many places through which city is being set. If you are doing it all in views repitively then you would be stuck at some point of time because to make smallest of changes, you might have to edit all the functions.

The good way would be to define `set_cities(self, cities)` in user model and  call it whenever needed like `user.set_cities(cities_list)`. So if you have to trigger other functions everytime city is being set (maybe like sending notifications or updating other tables), you have to define it once only in `set_cities()`.

In any case, all logic cannot be only in models so do not worry much about it. Just keep on trying to simplify the views and keep on shifting any repetition of logic to models.